# String split and compare - fastest method

Tags: java, string, performance, split

I have a string like:

1,2,3:3,4,5

The string on the left side of the delimiter needs to be compared to the string on the right side of the delimiter(`:`). Now when I mean compare, I actually mean to find if the elements in the right part `(3,4,5)` are present in the elements of the left part `(1,2,3)`. The right part can contain duplicates and that's fine (evidently meaning I cannot use a `HashSet`). I've accomplished this (details below) but I need the fastest way to split and compare the above mentioned strings.

This is purely a performance based question to find out which method can be faster since the actual input that I will be using is huge (on either side). There would be only a single line and it will be read through *stdin*.

How I've accomplished this:

1. Read *stdin*.
2. Split using string.split and store the left part in a `HashSet`.
3. Store the right part in an `ArrayList`.
4. Iterate through the array list use `contains()` to check if the element is present in the `HashSet`.

Comment: Concerning duplicates what you're saying about `HashSet` on the RHS makes no sense to me. IIUYC duplicates get ignored anywayas you don't count how many occurrences are there.

Comment: How large can the numbers be?

Comment: Ok, so the reason it makes no sense is because I cannot ignore a duplicate on the right side and when I encounter one, I have to flag that or simply put, do some other stuff with it. A single number can be anywhere between 10 to 15 digits.

Comment: @Subashini P: Then you have to use a `Set` for the RHS as well, as `set.add` tells you about the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read input into `byte[]` array to hold the pointer on the side of your code.
2. Read byte by byte, computing integer elements on the way:

   ```
   int b = inputBytes[p++];
   int d = b - '0';
   if (0 <= d) {
       if (d <= 9) {
           element = element * 10 + d;
       } else {
           // b == ':'
       }
   } else {
       // b == ','
       // add element to the hash; element = 0;
       ...
   }
   if (p == inputBytesLength) {
       inputBytesLength = in.read(inputBytes);
       if (inputBytesLength == 0) { ... }
       p = 0;
   }
   ```
3. Use `int[]` with length of sufficiently big power of two as hash:

   ```
   // as add()
   int h = element * 0x9E3779B9;
   int i = h >>> (32 - hashSizePower);
   while (hash[i] != 0) {
       if (--i < 0) i += hashSize;
   }
   hash[i] = element;

   // contains() similarly
   ```

Comment: Didn't you mean to use masking instead of modulus?

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, also added meanigful code to break element clusters in the hash set.

Comment: This looks good. I guess replacing `h ^= h >> (32 - hashSizePower);
int i = h & (hashSize - 1);` by just `int i = h >>> -hashSizePower` could make it even a bit faster. I'm too lazy to try it now, but I'm curious how much faster it is compared to the other answer.

Comment: Thanks guys - no offence but I'm a real newbie and dont know how to use your code - gets a little confusing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a line of input fits in JVM heap, three common approaches to parsing strings from input in Java are:

1. `java.util.Scanner`
2. `java.io.BufferedReader#readLine` & `java.util.StringTokenizer`
3. `java.io.BufferedReader#readLine` & `java.lang.String#split`

It wasn’t obvious to me which approach was best for this problem, so I decided to try it out. I generated test data, implemented a parser for each approach, and timed the results.

## Test Data

I generated 4 files of test data:

- testdata_1k.txt - size 20KB
- testdata_10k.txt - size 205KB
- testdata_100k.txt - size 2MB
- testdata_1000k.txt - size 20M

The files I generated matched the format you described. Each `,` delimited element is a random integer. The number in the file name describes the number of elements on each side if the `:`. For example, testdata_1k.txt has 1,000 elements on the left and 1,000 elements on the right.

## Test Code

Here's the code I used to test each approach. Please note, these are not examples of production quality code.

### Scanner Code

```
public Map<String, Boolean> scanner(InputStream stream) {
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(stream));
    final HashMap<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    final HashSet<String> left = new HashSet<String>();

    in.useDelimiter(",");
    boolean leftSide = true;
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String token = in.next();
        if (leftSide) {
            int delim = token.indexOf(':');
            if (delim >= 0) {
                left.add(token.substring(0, delim));
                String rightToken = token.substring(delim + 1, token.length());
                result.put(rightToken, left.contains(rightToken));
                leftSide = false;
            } else {
                left.add(token);
            }
        } else {
            result.put(token, left.contains(token));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

### StringTokenizer Code

```
public Map<String, Boolean> stringTokenizer(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    final HashMap<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    final StringTokenizer lineTokens = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine(), ":");
    final HashSet<String> left = new HashSet<String>();
    if (lineTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        final StringTokenizer leftTokens = new StringTokenizer(lineTokens.nextToken(), ",");
        while (leftTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            left.add(leftTokens.nextToken());
        }
    }
    if (lineTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        final StringTokenizer rightTokens = new StringTokenizer(lineTokens.nextToken(), ",");
        while (rightTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = rightTokens.nextToken();
            result.put(token, left.contains(token));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

### String.split Code

```
public Map<String, Boolean> split(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    final HashMap<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    final String[] splitLine = in.readLine().split(":");
    final HashSet<String> left = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(splitLine[0].split(",")));

    for (String element : splitLine[1].split(",")) {
        result.put(element, left.contains(element));
    }
    return result;
}
```

## Timing

I ran each approach 6 times against each file. I threw the first sample out. The following represents the average of the remaining 5 samples.

### Scanner

- testdata_1k.txt - 23.2948 millis
- testdata_10k.txt - 39.5036 millis
- testdata_100k.txt - 240.5626 millis
- testdata_1000k.txt - 2671.5132 millis

### StringTokenizer

- testdata_1k.txt - 31.2344 millis
- testdata_10k.txt -14.7926 millis
- testdata_100k.txt - 102.6412 millis
- testdata_1000k.txt - 1353.073 millis

### String.split

- testdata_1k.txt - 8.9596 millis
- testdata_10k.txt - 7.8396 millis
- testdata_100k.txt - 63.4854 millis
- testdata_1000k.txt - 947.8384 millis

## Conclusion

Assuming your data fits in JVM heap, it’s hard to beat the parsing speed of `String.split` compared to `StringTokenizer` and `Scanner`.